# Spring: separate datasource for read-only transactions

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ibatis

Thanks for reading this.

I have 2 MySQL databases - master for writes, slave for reads. The perfect scenario I imagine is that my app uses connection to master for `readOnly=false` transactions, slave for `readOnly=true` transactions.

In order to implement this I need to provide a valid connection depending on the type of current transaction. My data service layer should not know about what type of connection it uses and just use the injected `SqlMapClient` (I use iBatis) directly. This means that (if I get it right) the injected `SqlMapClient`s should be proxied and the delegate should be chosen at runtime.

```
public class MyDataService {

    private SqlMapClient sqlMap;

    @Autowired
    public MyDataService (SqlMapClient sqlMap) {
        this.sqlMap = sqlMap;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public MyData getSomeData() {
        // an instance of sqlMap connected to slave should be used
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveMyData(MyData myData) {
        // an instance of sqlMap connected to master should be used
    }
}
```

So the question is - how can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an interesting idea, but you'd have a tough job on your hands. The `readOnly` attribute is intended as a hint to the transaction manager, and isn't really consulted anywhere meaningful. You'd have to rewrite or extend multiple Spring infrastructure classes.

So unless you're hell-bent on getting this working a you want, your best option is almost certainly to inject two separate `SqlMapClient` objects into your DAO, and for the methods to pick the appropriate one. The `@Transactional` annotations would also need to indicate which transaction manager to use (assuming you're using `DataSourceTransactionManager` rather than `JpaTransactionManager`), taking care to match the transaction manager to the `DataSource` used by the `SqlMapClient`.

Comment: Is there an easier way with AspectJ for example?

Comment: @artemb: I.m sure AspectJ would help, but it's still not going to be easy.